# best practice towards ISO 19005-1

Tags: pdf-a

please recommend your experience concerning the creation of a PDF/A (ISO 19005-1) when using pdflatex. 
my thesis will be submitted to a plagiarism check. they demand PDF/A, but without any clear instructions which LaTeX commands should be used (documentclass options?) and what should be avoided.